# Getting an unique hash ID from array of UUIDs in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, hash, uuid

What is the best way to create a unique identifier for an array of UUIDs?

I have a Product that consists of multiple components, each component has an UUID assigned to it.

When creating a new Product with it's components, I need to know if there is already another product having exactly the same components. I think going through MySQL, loading each product with it's components and checking them one by one will be time consuming.

This is my idea:

```
products table
--------------
id, name, components_uuid_hash

product_components table
------------------------
product_id, component_id, ...

components table
----------------
id, uuid, name, ...
```

I would calculate the `components_uuid_hash`:

```
$product_component_uuids = ['227A0140-F0FB-4FDA-B780-85152AB02927', 'FA0E6D52-F0E4-4F55-87F5-8D73625AEDA3'];

sort($product_component_uuids);

$component_uuid_hash = md5(serialize($product_component_uuids));
```

I would do this for each product, giving me a unique hash of the whole UUID array that I could simply lookup in the `Products table` to know if there has already been a different product with the same hash.

Can someone please confirm if this would work or if there is a different better approach?

Comment: It would work :) you could probably also do this in a single query (i.e. without having to load everything at the PHP side), but it will not be able to use indexes (it will require a full JOIN between your tables and do a full scan).

Comment: Probably don't need to use serialize because it adds extraneous data.  md5(implode(",",$product_component_uuids)) should work as well

Comment: @obe thank you, I was just a bit afraid of relaying on the `sort()` function, but with UUIDs it shouldn't be a problem. I forgot to mention that those component UUIDs that I need to check against existing products are also coming from a 3rd party software in XML and having over 15k products each with 50 components I wanted to minimize the complexity of a query. Saving a hash and indexing the column should make it fast enough.

Comment: @DobromirVelev you are right, I was actually thinking about just separating the UUIDs by a comma, but for some reason having it serialized from an array felt more proper haha, although it doesn't make much sense here

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have a list of uuids you can try to do it in MySQL with something like

```
select pc.product_id, count(c.id) as co from 
product_components pc left join components c on (
  pc.component_id=c.id and
  c.uuid in ('227A0140-F0FB-4FDA-B780-85152AB02927', 'FA0E6D52-F0E4-4F55-87F5-8D73625AEDA3')
) 
group by pc.product_id having co=2;
```

This will return all products that have exactly two components with UUIDs matching those in the list.

You need to adjust the count value at the end to match the number of uuids.
This will still do a full scan on the product_components table and will probably use a temporary table, so your plan to keep a hash of the UUIDs in the products table and search by it will probably be faster from a MySQL point of view, but you will have to update it every time a product or a component changes.

Comment: Thank you, yes as I said in the comment above I have about 15k products each with 50+ components, so I want the search to be as lightweight as possible. Although the query you provided is really useful, I will definitely save it for later. I completely forgot abou the `having` clause. I also don't need to worry about about regenerating the hash, because it will be calculated when the product is approved in the system and from that point the components won't be changeable.